# Use field calculator to change values from a,b,c etc. to 1,2,3 etc.?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a vector shapefile with a column with string values. How can I convert this to a column of integer values in another column but keep the categorization.

e.g. from:

col1,newcol2
A,
A,
B,
A,
C,

to:

col1,newcol2
A,1
A,1
B,2
A,1
C,3

I'm sure it is in the 'replace' or 'case when' syntax somewhere but I cannot find a clear method via Google etc.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on your layer in the Layers Panel and then click on Open the Attribute table.

Click on Open field calculator (CTRL+I). There, create a new (virtual) field with the following expression:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN col1 = 'A' THEN 1
    WHEN col1 = 'B' THEN 2
    WHEN col1 = 'C' THEN 3
    ELSE 0
END
```

Edit: you can also use `strpos` to return the position of the letter:

```
strpos( 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', col1 )
```

[image: Strpos]

But I think you problem should be better solved by [joining a mapping table](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could create a Custom function in the Function Editor to use the python ORD() function to get the ASCII value of a character (A being 65):

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/custom_python_functions.html

The function might look like this:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def ord_place(value1, feature, parent):

    return ord(value1) - 64
```

Answer (score 1):

In your *Field Calculator* interface, go to the **Function Editor** tab, create a new file and input the following code:

```
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction
from qgis.core import QgsExpression, QgsMapLayerRegistry

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def stringtoNum(field, feature, parent):
    val = dict(zip(string.letters,[ord(c)%32 for c in string.letters]))
    return val[field]
```

Click *Load* then go back to the **Expression** tab, type in the details for your new field (name, type etc) and use the following expression:

```
stringtoNum("col1")
```

[image: Result]